# Как исключить отображение строки если у 1 и 2 столбца опредленные значения

Tags: mysql

Есть два столбца priner и service.
Надо исключить из отображения prinet Kyocera со значением второго service Заправка.
Но чтобы отображались другие принтеры и чтобы отображалась Kyocera с service Ремонт
SELECT * FROM `Applications` WHERE `printer_model` != 'Kyocera' and service = 'Заправка' Написал такой запрос, но теперь он не отображает Kyocera с ремонтом.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Надо исключить из отображения prinet Kyocera со значением второго service Заправка.* `WHERE (printer, service) <> ('Kyocera', 'Заправка')`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Applications` 
WHERE `printer_model` = 'Kyocera' and service !='Заправка' 
  and `printer_model` = 'Kyocera' and service !='Очистка' 
   or printer_model != 'Kyocera'
```

Сделал как хотел.